# How to print stack in libui

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to print stack in libui, so i uncomment the line in frameworks/native/libs/ui/Android.bp

```
//defaults: ["libui-validate-regions-defaults"],
```

[frameworks/native/libs/ui/Android.bp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/native/libs/ui/Android.bp;drc=86c54bd9aa36e81079da83a85677f42b84a8869f;l=159)

Then rom build failed:

```
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z] error: frameworks/av/apex/Android.bp:248:1: module "com.android.media.swcodec" variant "android_common_cfi_com.android.media.swcodec_image": "libui" requires "libutilscallstack" that doesn't list the APEX under 'apex_available'.
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z] Dependency path:
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag apex.dependencyTag{"executable"}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> mediaswcodec{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.libraryDependencyTag: { Kind:sharedLibraryDependency Order:normalLibraryDependency wholeStatic:false reexportFlags:false explicitlyVersioned:false dataLib:false ndk:false staticUnwinder:false makeSuffix: skipApexAllowedDependenciesCheck:false excludeInApex:false unexportedSymbols:false}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libmedia_codecserviceregistrant{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.dependencyTag: { name:reuse objects}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libmedia_codecserviceregistrant{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:static,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.installDependencyTag: { InstallAlwaysNeededDependencyTag:{} name:runtime lib}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libcodec2_soft_avcdec{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.libraryDependencyTag: { Kind:sharedLibraryDependency Order:normalLibraryDependency wholeStatic:false reexportFlags:false explicitlyVersioned:false dataLib:false ndk:false staticUnwinder:false makeSuffix: skipApexAllowedDependenciesCheck:false excludeInApex:false unexportedSymbols:false}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libcodec2_vndk{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.libraryDependencyTag: { Kind:sharedLibraryDependency Order:normalLibraryDependency wholeStatic:false reexportFlags:false explicitlyVersioned:false dataLib:false ndk:false staticUnwinder:false makeSuffix: skipApexAllowedDependenciesCheck:false excludeInApex:false unexportedSymbols:false}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libui{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.libraryDependencyTag: { Kind:sharedLibraryDependency Order:normalLibraryDependency wholeStatic:false reexportFlags:false explicitlyVersioned:false dataLib:false ndk:false staticUnwinder:false makeSuffix: skipApexAllowedDependenciesCheck:false excludeInApex:false unexportedSymbols:false}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libutilscallstack{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z] Consider adding "com.android.media.swcodec" to 'apex_available' property of "libutilscallstack"
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z] error: frameworks/av/apex/Android.bp:248:1: module "com.android.media.swcodec" variant "android_common_cfi_com.android.media.swcodec_image": "libutilscallstack" requires "libutilscallstack" that doesn't list the APEX under 'apex_available'.
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z] Dependency path:
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag apex.dependencyTag{"executable"}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> mediaswcodec{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.libraryDependencyTag: { Kind:sharedLibraryDependency Order:normalLibraryDependency wholeStatic:false reexportFlags:false explicitlyVersioned:false dataLib:false ndk:false staticUnwinder:false makeSuffix: skipApexAllowedDependenciesCheck:false excludeInApex:false unexportedSymbols:false}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libmedia_codecserviceregistrant{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.dependencyTag: { name:reuse objects}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libmedia_codecserviceregistrant{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:static,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.installDependencyTag: { InstallAlwaysNeededDependencyTag:{} name:runtime lib}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libcodec2_soft_avcdec{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.libraryDependencyTag: { Kind:sharedLibraryDependency Order:normalLibraryDependency wholeStatic:false reexportFlags:false explicitlyVersioned:false dataLib:false ndk:false staticUnwinder:false makeSuffix: skipApexAllowedDependenciesCheck:false excludeInApex:false unexportedSymbols:false}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libcodec2_vndk{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.libraryDependencyTag: { Kind:sharedLibraryDependency Order:normalLibraryDependency wholeStatic:false reexportFlags:false explicitlyVersioned:false dataLib:false ndk:false staticUnwinder:false makeSuffix: skipApexAllowedDependenciesCheck:false excludeInApex:false unexportedSymbols:false}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libui{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.libraryDependencyTag: { Kind:sharedLibraryDependency Order:normalLibraryDependency wholeStatic:false reexportFlags:false explicitlyVersioned:false dataLib:false ndk:false staticUnwinder:false makeSuffix: skipApexAllowedDependenciesCheck:false excludeInApex:false unexportedSymbols:false}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libutilscallstack{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:shared,version:,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]            via tag cc.dependencyTag: { name:reuse objects}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]     -> libutilscallstack{os:android,image:,arch:arm64_armv8-a-branchprot,sdk:,link:static,apex:apex31}
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z]
[2024-02-22T09:42:04.686Z] Consider adding "com.android.media.swcodec" to 'apex_available' property of "libutilscallstack"

......
......
......
......
```

I have tried many solutions, but all failed.
Please help to solve the problems.Thanks!